# C++ STL vector with odd size, 0 capacity before anything is added

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am debugging an issue where there is a seg fault when trying to call push_back to a vector.  The seg fault is on the first attempt to add anything to the vector.  For debug purposes, I printed out capacity and size before this first attempt, and the result is size: 529486, and capacity: 0.

The frustrating part is that this is an add-on vector, following the same formula used to work with other vectors, and those work.  The size and capacity behave as expected with these other vectors.

As rough pseudo-code for what I am doing:

```
class NEWTYPE{

public:
    Object* objPtr;

    NEWTYPE();
    void update(float );
    void setObject(Object* o);

};

class ABCD{
    std::vector<TYPE1*> type1List;
    std::vector<TYPE2*> type2List;
    std::vector<TYPE3*> type3List;
    std::vector<TYPE4*> type4List;
    std::vector<TYPE5*> type5List;  // <== there were 5 other vectors working
    std::vector<NEWTYPE*> NEWTYPEList;

}
void ABCD::addType1(TYPE1* n){
    cout << type1List.size() << type1List.capacity;  // <== as expected
    type1List.push_back(n);  // <== Works for each old type
}
void ABCD::addNewType(NEWTYPE* n){
    cout << NEWTYPEList.size() << NEWTYPEList.capacity;  // size: 529486, capacity:0 before first call 
    NEWTYPEList.push_back(n); // <== seg fault
}

ABCD instance;
// foo() : This procedure works correctly for the other vectors
void foo(){
    NEWTYPE* test;
    test = new NEWTYPE();
  instance.addNewType(test);
}
```

I am not quite at a point to try to extract things to reproduce in a simple test case.  That is one of my next steps.

Anyway, if anyone can point me in the right direction on this, I appreciate the advice.  Thanks!

Comment: Please prepare a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: There could be zillions of things but it boils down to this: *Memory corruption*. Over/underflow, garbage/dangling pointer, returning the address of a temporary, incorrect copy constructor / assignment operator etc...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this turned out to be a build-related issue.

I updated the "master class" (ABCD in the pseudocode) to add the new vector.  However, the file that declared the instance was not being rebuilt.  The push_back function call was called for a vector that did not exist.

FYI...sorry for not being clear on my original question.  Since I was using the same procedures as working parts of the code, my line of thinking was that I may have violated some stack constraint, or exceeded some default setting for vector related to how many vectors were being used.

Answer (score -1):

Garbage returned by `std::vector::capacity()` and `std::vector::size()` most probably point to an uninitialized object. As object in your example is global I suspect function `foo` called from another global object constructor. As order of initialization of global objects is not defined you can have different behavior with different instances of vectors. Possible solution - use singleton object with a local static object:

```
ABCD &getInstance()
{
    static ABCD theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}
```

this way `theInstance` will be initialized when function `getInstance()` is called first time. This method does not solve issue with destructor order though, you should design your program the way that destrutcors of global objects should not call methods of other global objects, or use different singleton type (for example phoenix).

Comment: Downvoted, poor answer to a poor question. You provide a solution of sorts and directly argue against its use.